# Find angle of line tangent to a circle based on these parameters?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohw0q.jpg) is an image showing the problem I'm faced with.

[image]

All variables in the picture are known except for beta (ß). That is what I'm trying to find.

I have a circle of radius *r* that's a distance *h* from some (black) reference line.

From that reference line, there's an angled line (in green) that's tangent to the circle.

The starting location of that angled tangent line is a distance *d* from the vertical tangent of the circle (vertical in the sense that it is perpendicular to the black reference line).

**If *h*, *r*, and *d* are known/given, how can I derive a formula to calculate ß?**

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

the tangent line has the equation
$$x\tan(\beta)-y=0$$

the center of the circle has cordinates

$$(h,d+r)$$

the distance between this center and the tangent line must be $ r$, so

$$\frac{|h\tan(\beta)-(d+r)|}{\sqrt{\tan^2(\beta)+1}}=r$$

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to solve for ß in that final equation? That's the variable I'm most interested in calculating.

Comment: @tectactoe Yes, use the identity $1+\tan^2=\frac {1}{\cos^2}$

Comment: Square the last equation, multiply both sides by $\tan^2\beta+1$ and you get a quadratic in $\tan\beta$.